# System.Web.Http assembly not allways visible in same c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies

I have a C# project where in my controller class the System.Web.Http library can be referenced but in the another class it cannot.  The reference has been added to the overall project and both classes have all the necessary using directives.

The Request method of System.Web.Http cannot be resolved in some instances?

Here are code snippets of the two classes:

Controllers/FormsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using FormsImport.Models;

namespace FormsImport.Controllers
{
    public class TCSTasksController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("api/TCSUploadFile")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadCSVFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);  // <-- the name Request does exists
.
.
.
}
```

CSVmanager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;  //<-- Compiler claims this directive is unneccesary
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using FormsImport.Models;


namespace FormsImport
{
    public class CSVmgr
    {

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadCSVFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created); // <-- the name Request Does not exist in the current context

.
.
.
}
```

Comment: `Request` is a property on `ApiController`. Where are you expecting `CSVmgr` to get it from?

Comment: It claims that System.Web.Http is not necessary because it is. You are not using nor inherit any type which is from that namespace.

Comment: What makes you think this is an error? Does this result in a compiler error of any kind (besides the warning about the unnecessary `using` directive)?

Comment: I see! It's a protected function of that Class and can't be called standalone.  So if I want that other class to perform some of the work of the controller I must pass the controller reference to that other class in some manner.

Comment: No it doesn't compile!  The reference to Request is does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should agree with your compiler/IDE (Visual Studio?) in this case - it's simply pointing out that the referenced assembly is not in use in this class.

Should you decide to use any functionality from this assembly, the warning in question will go away.

**EDIT based on comment:** If the functionality you need is part of a `protected` interface of another class, such as `ApiController`, you MUST extend that class to access such functionality in your own class. If such extension subsequently uses methods in the assembly you referenced (and for which the compiler shows an unnecessary `using` directive), the compiler warning regarding the `using` directive will likewise resolve.

Comment: It fails to compile because the Request method is a protected Function of the ApiController class of which my new class does not inherit from.  ApiController.Request() cannot to used like the static function System.IO.Path() for instance.

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI - how would referencing the assembly help in this case??? Protected method can only be accessed by the declaring class or a child class.

Answer (score 0):

in your api controller, Request is a HttpRequestMessage type, and the CreateResponse is the extension method of HttpRequestMessage. why not create a HttpResponseMessage new instance in your CSVmgr class. like:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is the easiest solution that worked!

Answer (score 0):

codran 17 explained it the best.

My new class is not derived from the APIController Class and the Request method of that class is not a static function that I can call like System.IO.Path() for instance.  So I must use another static function from a class that returns the same results or pass a reference to the APIController to my new class.

Like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadCSVFile(ApiController controller)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = controller.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
```